# JavaFX - Drawing an Object with changing property (position) on a canvas

Tags: java, model-view-controller, canvas, javafx

I am trying to create a project in JavaFX where - robots represented by points - move around on a canvas based on some communication protocoll. By now, I have figured out that following the MVC-approach, I should keep the relevant data (robots) in an Object of type ObservableList, which the controller can then use to update the canvas.

Running the Controller.java's test() method I get the following Error which I am unable to resolve. I have commented the relevant line in the Controller.java - removing it also resolves the error message.

I realize that this approach may be far from what is best practice. I would be very much grateful for any hints at how I can resolve this issue or make better use of an Observable, to allow the controller to draw the robots position on the canvas after it has changed.

Main.java

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main extends Application {

    public Stage primaryStage;
    private BorderPane rootLayout;
    private final Model model = new Model();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

        //    this.model = new Model();
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        this.primaryStage.setTitle("");
        initRootLayout();

    }

    public void initRootLayout(){
        try {

            // Load root layout from fxml file.
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("Overview.fxml"));
            rootLayout = (BorderPane) loader.load();

            // Show the scene containing the root layout.
            Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.setHeight(500);
            primaryStage.setWidth(500);

            // Give the controller access to the main app.
            Controller controller = loader.getController();
            controller.initModel(model);



            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Model.java

```
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

public class Model {

    private final ObservableList<Robot> robots = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    public ObservableList<Robot> getRobots(){ return robots;}

}
```

Robot.java

```
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;

import java.util.Random;

public class Robot implements Runnable {


    private IntegerProperty id = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    public void setID(int id){this.id.set(id);}
    public int getId(){ return this.id.get();};
    private Memory memory;

    private DoubleProperty positionX = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
    public double getPositionX() {return positionX.get();};
    public DoubleProperty positionXProperty(){ return positionX;}

    private DoubleProperty positionY = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
    public double getPositionY() {return positionY.get();};
    public DoubleProperty positionYProperty(){ return positionY;}

    public void setPosition (double x, double y){

        this.positionX.set(x);
        this.positionY.set(y);
        this.memory.setPosition(x,y);

    }

    // Constructor
    public Robot(int id, double x, double y){

        this.setID(id);
        memory = new Memory();
        this.setPosition(x, y);

    }



    public double[] getPosition(){
        double [] ret = new double[2];
        ret[0] = this.memory.getPosition()[0];
        ret[1] = this.memory.getPosition()[1];
        return ret;
    }

    public void move (double targetx, double targety){
        System.out.println("Agent carrying " + this.getId + " has moved from " + this.getPositionX() + " / " + this.getPositionY() + " to " + targetx + " / " + targety + " ." );
        this.setPosition(targetx, targety);


    }

    public void run(){

        while(true){
            // the robot gets assigned a new position based on a communication
            // protocoll used by the Robots which I have removed for convenience
            Random r = new Random();
            double nextX = 0 + (100) * r.nextDouble();
            double nextY = 0 + (100) * r.nextDouble();
            this.move(nextX, nextY);

            try{
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Memory.java

```
public class Memory {

    double[] position = new double[2];
    double[] plast = new double[2];

    // constructor
    public Memory(){

        double[] position = new double[2];
        double[] plast = new double[2];

    }

    public double[] getPosition(){
        return position;
    }


    public double[] getLastPosition(){
        return plast;
    }

    public void  setLastPosition(double x, double y){
        plast[0] = x;
        plast[1] = y;
    }
    public void setPosition(double x, double y){
        position[0] = x;
        position[1] = y;
    }


}
```

Controller.java

```
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class Controller {

    private Model model;

    public void initModel(Model model) {
        this.model = model ;

        for (Robot robot : model.getRobots()){
            robot.positionXProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
                    System.out.println("Observed change in value X of Robot carrying ID: " + robot.getId());
                    drawPoint(robot.getPositionX(), robot.getPositionY());
                    // if I comment out the above line I get no errors
                }
            });
            robot.positionYProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
                    System.out.println("Observed change in value Y of Robot carrying ID: " + robot.getId());
                    drawPoint(robot.getPositionX(), robot.getPositionY());
                    // if I comment out the above line I get no errors
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @FXML
    Canvas canvas;


    public void test(){
        GraphicsContext gc =canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        gc.strokeRect(0,0,100,100);

        Robot a = new Robot(0,25,25);
        Robot b = new Robot(1,50,50);

        model.getRobots().add(a);
        model.getRobots().add(b);

        Thread ta = new Thread(a);
        Thread tb = new Thread(b);

        initModel(model);

        System.out.println("Starting threads.");
        ta.start();
        tb.start();


    }

    public void drawPoint(double x, double y){
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        gc.setFill(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0));
        gc.fillOval(x, y, 5, 5);
    }
}
```

Overview.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.canvas.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Controller">
   <top>
      <Button fx:id="buttonTest" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#test" text="test()" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </top>
   <center>
      <Canvas fx:id="canvas" height="200.0" width="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Error:

```
java.lang.InternalError: Unrecognized PGCanvas token: -96
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGCanvas.renderStream(NGCanvas.java:1146)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGCanvas.renderContent(NGCanvas.java:595)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2067)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1959)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:235)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:576)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2067)
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1959)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.doPaint(ViewPainter.java:474)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.paintImpl(ViewPainter.java:327)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PresentingPainter.run(PresentingPainter.java:91)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.RenderJob.run(RenderJob.java:58)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: If you are asking about code that generates errors at run time, you should post an example that actually compiles. There are multiple compile errors in this. To create a [MCVE] you should actually create the code, run ti to verify it demonstrates the problems you are addressing, and then copy the code directly here. This is not code you have run. I also recommend you follow the [Java FX Properties pattern](http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=javase80&id=JFXBD107), since you are using JavaFX properties.

Comment: Dear James_D, thank you for your reply. I appreciate your input and regret not double checking the code I submitted. I have fixed all compile errors, thus the code should now be runnable. The error message is identical to the one I previously submitted. I tried following the _Java FX Properties pattern_ in the Robot class as you suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are observing the coordinates of the robots, and changing the UI in response, you must change the coordinates on the FX Application Thread in order to abide by the JavaFX single threading rules. (You could conceivably have the listeners schedule the change to the UI on the FX Application Thread, but then you would have to worry about synchronization on the coordinates as they would be accessed from two different threads.)

So your `run()` method should look like

public void run(){

```
    while(true){
        // the robot gets assigned a new position based on a communication
        // protocoll used by the Robots which I have removed for convenience

        Platform.runLater(() -> {

            Random r = new Random();
            double nextX = 0 + (100) * r.nextDouble();
            double nextY = 0 + (100) * r.nextDouble();
            this.move(nextX, nextY);

        });

        try{
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

That fixes the immediate problem; you may find there are others.